# Error: Migration dependencies reference nonexistent parent node

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I get this error when I run migration with Sudo permission:

```py
  File "/home/dell/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration auth.0013_auto_20210105_1445 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length')
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You probably have a problem with your code, we need you to post the relevant code to help you

Comment: Your latest migration, `0013_auto_20210105_1445`, seems to reference the previous migration, `0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length`, which no longer exists for some reason. Maybe you have deleted it?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me when I upgraded from django

> V3.0.2

to

> V3.2.3

then **DOWNGRADE AGAIN** to

> V3.0.2

I resolved the conflict by just removing the migration file -in your case it will be **0013_auto_20210105_1445.py**- witch was located -in my case- in

`PATH/TO/VIRTUAL_ENV/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations`

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete this migration, because it dependencies at last

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30833545)